# Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined. React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting the error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  // categories
  const { data: categories }: AxiosResponse<ICollectionResponse<ICategory[]>> =
    await fetchCategories();

  return {
    props: {
      categories: {
        items: categories.data,
      },
    },
  };
};
```

```
export interface ICategory {
id: number;
attributes: ICategoryAttribute;
}

export interface ICategoryAttribute {
Title: string;
Slug: string;
}

export interface IPagination {
page: number;
pageSize: number;
pageCount: number;
total: number;
}

export interface IResourceMeta {
pagination: IPagination;
}

export interface ICollectionResponse<T> {
data: T;
meta: IResourceMeta;
}
```

Fetching categories

```
import axios from "axios"
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BACKEND_API_KEY}`,
    },
});
//categories
export const fetchCategories = async () => {api.get('/api/categories')};
```

[image]

Comment: So, the issue is before you are getting a value from the promise, which you are assuming is an object, is not know to JS, TS. So, Its assuming undefined and causing the bug. Simply add a if condition and do the check

Comment: Remove the `{}`. `export const fetchCategories = async () => api.get('/api/categories');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deconstruct the object once it's resolved

```
const response: AxiosResponse<ICollectionResponse<ICategory[]>> = await fetchCategories();

const {data: categories} = response
```

return the axio get

```
export const fetchCategories = () => {return api.get('/api/categories')};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. tried this way but same error occurring

Comment: post the code for `fetchCategories`

Comment: added the interface code

Comment: not the interface `fetchCategories` method

Comment: fetching categories from api(CMS). added that code now

Comment: see the updated